# WarningVariable no working with Set-CasMailbox in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Running the following command

```
set-casmailbox -Identity $DN -ActiveSyncAllowedDeviceIDs @{ add = $DeviceID }
```

sometimes brings a warning

```
WARNING: The command completed successfully but no settings of 'User Name' have been modified.
```

If I add `-WarningVariable` and `-WarningAction`, the messages are not sent to the console, but the warning is not passed to the variable

```
set-casmailbox -WarningVariable WarVar -Identity $DN -ActiveSyncAllowedDeviceIDs @{ add = $DeviceID }
```

To calrify all I am doing is calling $WarVar

full script would be

```
set-casmailbox -WarningVariable WarVar -Identity $DN -ActiveSyncAllowedDeviceIDs @{ add = $DeviceID }
$WarVar
```

Comment: Normally it works like this. Please show the code where you use `$WarVar` afterwards.

Comment: I have edited the question, but all i do is call $WarVar. I have tried variants $WarVar.count $WarVar.TargetObject and I've looked during a debug session using VScode - it houses no value

Comment: I don't see any error on your side. It's possibly a bug in `set-casmailbox`. As a workaround you could try to redirect the warning stream like this: `$WarVar = @(); set-casmailbox -Identity $DN -ActiveSyncAllowedDeviceIDs @{ add = $DeviceID } 3>&1 | ForEach-Object { if( $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.WarningRecord] ) { $WarVar += $_ } else { $_ } }`

Comment: Using `3>&1` would merge the warning stream with the success stream, so you could process it by `ForEach-Object`. When the current object is a warning message, add it to variable `$WarVar`, otherwise output the object normally.